# Computer suspends on pressing left ctrl key in two OS : Elementary and Ubuntu 16.04. What could be wrong with my keyboard or motherboard?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, motherboard, freeze, suspend

Problem: Left CRTL does all the functions a ctrl key should do, except 7 times out of 10, it suspends the computer. The exact same thing a power button does. What could be wrong here? Is it the keyboard or the motherboard? I had issues where the laptop was not switching on and I had to keep pressing the power button a lot of times!
Also, since I barely use Ubuntu 16.04, it can be considered a fresh installation. Same problem persists there as well!

Also, the computer freezes quite frequently even though I don't have Nvidia's graphic card driver installed, which is known for causing such problems. When it freezes, I'm not able to switch to ttys using crtl+alt+funtion keys. But fortunately, once I was in tty4 and it froze, giving me this output:
[Logs through tty4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxZ0i.jpg)

[Here's the output containing my pc's hardware information](http://codepaste.net/qjb5z4) that I get after  `sudo lshw -short`

Comment: 1. contextual shortcut key combination depending on which application or part of OS you have context during the key press. App/OS separate key combinations?

Comment: @mnmnc Nope. The first thing that I did was check for key combinations. I use chrome mostly (webdev) and there can't be any such combination that suspends it 7 times when the key is pressed 10.

Comment: So you are pressing CTRL key by itself 10 times and it shuts down the computer? you dont press any other key at this time? Maybe try with other keyboard? Maybe this one is faulty. Try with on-screen-keyboard. Get back with results

Comment: This is so annoying, for some time it happened then the problem just dissappeared, now I suspect that a recent update messed again my kb or something

Comment: also, when I press the volume-up button, it redirects the url of my website to home. Da hell is goin on!

Comment: @mnmnc No. I just said, I dont have t ohit the left ctrl (or sometimes shift key) 10 times. It's just that it happened at random. I'm not able to work on Ubuntu 16.06 or Elementary (ElementaryOS got updated to have some features of ubuntu 16.06). I suspect the problem is that they are over heating the laptop, and the freezing is because of that. The suspend on key pressing maybe just a random coincidence as I frequently use left crtl/shift keys (several times in a minute).

Comment: I tried Opensuse, although the freezing problem is not that frequent, but still it happens after a considerable time. (In other OSes there was freezing as well as laptop got suspended a lot on keypress). I think it's hardware problem. There could be overheating, I tried speeding up the fan speed, but [unfortunately I'm not able to](http://superuser.com/questions/1131540/fan-speed-not-increasing-in-opensuse-pwmconfig-doesnt-detect-fan) 
Also in Opensuse, once it freezes,  the network card gets disabled. wlan stops working. I have to wait for 10-20 mins after shutdown to get it working.

Comment: I thought it could be problem with the kernel that all of my OSes are using, and I tried upgrading the kernel. The installation fails giving so many errors that it's impossible for me to fix each of them. :(